# How do I change my monitor's resolution when using a KVM?

Tags: xorg, display, kvm-switch

I'm using 10.04 behind a KVM switch. The KVM is old and doesn't pass DDC through, so when the box boots up it just assumes I can't handle anything beyond 800x600. Apparently the xorg.conf is ignored, so I can't just hack monitor data directly into that. Is there a way to tell the box what my monitor is that will persist across reboots?

Answer (score 3):

Hardcoding an xorg.conf is the most traditional solution to dealing with this problem.  What is causing your xorg.conf to get overwritten?

You didn't mention what graphics hardware or video driver you're using, but if it is a KMS enabled driver, you may need to turn KMS off.

Comment: It turns out it's not actually being overwritten; it's just being ignored.